# Re: Relation Module

Tags: entities

I have/had been working on a 'self-learning' development project based on a D7 stack and utilsing the http://drupal.org/project/recruit* however the author earlier this year ceased development. I had continued with it, but as I continuously upgraded D7.14 and it's modules, found that the above had become no longer useable. Very recently I came across' http://drupal.org/project/relation so am now currently looking to re-build the previous functionality with Relation and the Views/Panels/Rules stack and have studied the online tutorials such as: http://nodeone.se/en/introduction-to-relation which gives me the impression that Relation is the right road for this project and many other Drupal projects I may creatively develop. (*I don't want to use any of the other similar O-T-S packages nor 'hack' them).

Whilst Relation looks very promising and appears extremely functional to my needs, I'd appreciative (by way of comments/feedback here) opinions  (from other Drupal developers (who have a longer programming experience than my current 12 months P/T learning) in that I am indeed focused on the correct module to provide the similar required functionality. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I simply agreed with Boombatowers assesment, that you are on the right way.

However, after reading the description of the Recruit page more carefully, I notice that it actually provides integration with Relation already.

I'm not familiar at all with the Recruit module, but I see a large risk that you simply end up duplicating a lot of the effort that has already gone into Recruit. Getting co-maintainership or [Taking over](https://drupal.org/node/251466) the existing module may end up saving you vast amounts of time.

Comment: Again Thank you for your reply and in response, refer to my boombatower reply above. Further to yours, I'm glad of the confirmation to my initial thoughts re; the old recruit module. I agree with you that duplicating effort is not what I want, but as said above whilst I've been an IT user for 25 years, I'm not currently too confident to 'hack' a module until my programming ability has increased over then next few weeks. I'm glad to read that 'provides integration with Relation already' so at least I'm on the right track. cont..

Comment: ..maintaining or 'taking over' might not be worth it and probably better I find a way and share it my results here with others for future use. It's possible that some of the Recruit module was for me 'too heavy' and I merely need to incorporate an "Apply Now" on each job node and then have that linked via Relation to the content posters (and applications) dashboard. I know others have done some great work with the "Recruiter"/Drop_jobs but IMO they lack certain aspects which I'd like to build upon from a commercial/ organisational aspect. I'll keep people posted on how I overcome my issues.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the specific functionality that the recruit project attempts to provide, but from reading the project page it seems like there are a number of relationships that would be well suited for relation. One thing I have used relation for in more complex scenarios is to keep track the state between two objects with a field on the relation which seems like something you may need to do.

From what I can tell what you propose makes sense, but I do not have all the details.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment regarding the 'two objects with a field' is something I had in mind, possible using the 'contextual link' module long with Rules/Views etc. At this moment in time neither of my php or module dev is sufficient as I'm currently learning php (also Python and Javascript) via online sourses/self-study so once my confidence has increased I'll take that route; I'm not afraid to 'hack' mind a module and give it ago. I'll consider my hunch for now and get back to post, once I've accomplished something.